# Bash script: split word on each letter

Tags: command-line, split, words

How can I split a word's letters, with each letter in a separate line?

For example, given `"StackOver"` 
I would like to see

```
S
t
a
c
k
O
v
e
r
```

I'm new to bash so I have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I would use `grep`:

```
$ grep -o . <<<"StackOver"
S
t
a
c
k
O
v
e
r
```

or `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/./&\n/g' <<<"StackOver"
S
t
a
c
k
O
v
e
r
```

And if empty space at the end is an issue:

```
sed 's/\B/&\n/g' <<<"StackOver"
```

All of that assuming GNU/Linux.

Comment: grep -o .  <<< ¿¿¿ .. -o searches for the PATTERN provided right? and what it does here in your command?

Comment: @SijaanHallak `grep` searches for pattern, an in this example it searches for every character `.` and prints it in the separate line. See also `sed ` solution.

Comment: Thanks! so this "." dot means every character.. Can you please give me a link where I can read about things such as this dot? or what ar these things called?

Comment: Note that both `-o` and `\n` are a GNU extension. `<<<` is a zsh extension (also available in recent versions of ksh93 and the GNU shell (bash)).

Comment: @SijaanHallak The best manual you have already on you computer, just run `man grep` and then just look for the chapter "REGULAR EXPRESSIONS" (if that is what you are interested in).

Comment: Second answer would produce a new line  after last...

Comment: @jimmij I cant find any help on what  <<<  really does! 
any help?

Comment: @SijaanHallak This is so called `Here string`, grosso modo equivalent of `echo foo | ...` just less typing. See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html

Comment: @jimmij the second solution here seems to have a problem. it prints a new line at the end!
I changed it to this `sed -e 's/./\n&/g' <<< "$1"`
But this prints a new line at the beggining.. any suggestion how to overcome this?

Comment: @SijaanHallak change `.` to `\B` (doesn't match on word boundary).

Comment: @jimmij \B will not work as it prints "Stack Over" -> the "O" will be printed near the letter "k" at the same line and then it does `\n`

Comment: I ended up uding this! it works perfectly 
` a=`sed  's/./&\n/g' <<<"$1"` `
 `echo "$a" | sed 's/\b/&/' `

Comment: @SijaanHallak - you can drop the second `sed` like: `sed -et -e's/./\n&/g;//D'`

Comment: cool solution 

Answer (score 20):

You may want to break on grapheme clusters instead of characters if the intent is to print text vertically. For instance with a `e` with an acute accent:

- With grapheme clusters (`e` with its acute accent would be **one** grapheme cluster):

  ```
  $ perl -CLAS -le 'for (@ARGV) {print for /\X/g}' $'Ste\u301phane'
  S
  t
  é
  p
  h
  a
  n
  e
  ```

  (or `grep -Po '\X'` with GNU grep built with PCRE support)
- With characters (here with GNU `grep`):

  ```
  $ printf '%s\n' $'Ste\u301phane' | grep -o .
  S
  t
  e

  p
  h
  a
  n
  e
  ```
- `fold` is meant to break on characters, but GNU `fold` doesn't support multi-byte characters, so it breaks on bytes instead:

  ```
  $ printf '%s\n' $'Ste\u301phane' | fold -w 1
  S
  t
  e
  �
  �
  p
  h
  a
  n
  e
  ```

On *StackOver* which only consists of ASCII characters (so one byte per character, one character per grapheme cluster), all three would give the same result.

Comment: I'm surprised `grep -Po` doesn't do what one would expect (like `grep -P` does).

Comment: @jimmij, what do you mean? `grep -Po .` finds characters (and a combining acute accent following a newline character is invalid), and `grep -Po '\X'` finds graphem clusters for me. You may need a recent version of grep and/or PCRE for it to work properly (or try `grep -Po '(*UTF8)\X'`)

Comment: @SijaanHallak These might be helpful: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html, http://eev.ee/blog/2015/09/12/dark-corners-of-unicode/

Comment: Are you claiming that `$'e\u301'` is equivalent/equal to `é` ?

Comment: @Isaac, no, I'm not claiming any such thing though there are some definitions of "equivalent" for which that would be true.

Comment: Your description seems to imply that because Perl is able to join together characters and accents (much like a text editor join them to select an specific glyph) other software should be able also. But no, not all programs are text editors, Nor all utilities understand the **complex** (specially in Hangul) set of rules to join some individual Unicode codepoints (https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/ and search for Devanagari kshi). So, no, nor grep, sed or fold understand any of this issue (yet).

Answer (score 7):

If you have [perl6](http://perl6.org/) in your box:

```
$ perl6 -e 'for @*ARGS -> $w { .say for $w.comb }' 'cường'       
c
ư
ờ
n
g
```

work regardless of your locale.

Answer (score 6):

With many `awk` versions

```
awk -F '' -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1};1' <<<'StackOver'
```

Comment: Great! But on my version of nAWK ("One True AWK") that doesn't work. However this does the trick: `awk -v FS='' -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1};1'` _(wondering if that's more portable since `-F ''` might yield the ERE: `//`)_

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`fold (1)`](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=fold+-b1+%3C%3C%3C+%22StackOver%22) command.  It is more efficient than `grep` and `sed`.

```
$ time grep -o . <bigfile >/dev/null

real    0m3.868s
user    0m3.784s
sys     0m0.056s
$ time fold -b1 <bigfile >/dev/null

real    0m0.555s
user    0m0.528s
sys     0m0.016s
$
```

One significant difference is that fold will reproduce empty lines in the output:

```
$ grep -o . <(printf "A\nB\n\nC\n\n\nD\n")
A
B
C
D
$ fold -b1 <(printf "A\nB\n\nC\n\n\nD\n")
A
B

C


D
$
```

Answer (score 5):

```
echo StackOver | sed -e 's/./&\n/g'
S
t
a
c
k
O
v
e
r
```

Comment: This won't help as it prints a new line at the end

Answer (score 4):

You can handle multibyte characters like:

```
<input \
dd cbs=1 obs=2 conv=unblock |
sed -e:c -e '/^.*$/!N;s/\n//;tc'
```

Which can be pretty handy when you're working with *live* input because there's no buffering there and a character is printed as soon it is *whole*.

Comment: NP, should we add a note about the locale?

Comment: Does not work for combining characters like Stéphane Chazelas answer, but with proper normalization this should not matter.

Comment: @Kay - it's works for combining characters if you *want* it to - that's what `sed` scripts are for. i'm not likely to write one right about now - im pretty sleepy. it's really useful, though, when reading a terminal.

Comment: @cuonglm - if you like. it should just work for the locale, given a sane libc, though.

Comment: Note that `dd` will break multibyte characters, so the output will not be text anymore so the behaviour of sed will be unspecified as per POSIX.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - do you have a link to reference that statement? a NUL can't occur in a multibyte character, and a dot can only match a whole character which is not NUL, and it has worked with every `sed` i've tried. how could it not work?

Comment: oh wait - you mean because input isn't a text file. possibly, but sed is spec'd to handle conditions which exceed/break text file specs, too, such as 4k pattern spaces scripts which is well beyond line max. its also spec'd to evaluate chars bytewise w/ `l` - even when a single char is multiple bytes. i think the text file restriction for sed is probably based on the NUL prohibition - many seds replace `delimiter` in their scripts w/ NULs, and ive never managed to seek past a NUL in pattern space with heirloom sed except with D and G.

Answer (score 4):

The below will be generic:

```
$ awk -F '' \
   'BEGIN { RS = ""; OFS = "\n"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i = $i; print }' <file_name>
```

Answer (score 4):

Also [Python 2](https://www.python.org/) can be used from the command line:

```
python <<< "for x in 'StackOver':
   print x"
```

or:

```
echo "for x in 'StackOver':
    print x" | python
```

or (as commented by 1_CR) with [Python 3](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/):

```
python3 -c "print(*'StackOver',sep='\n')"
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you specifically asked for an answer in bash, here's a way to do it in pure bash:

```
while read -rn1; do echo "$REPLY" ; done <<< "StackOver"
```

Note that this will catch the newline at the end of the "[here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)". If you want to avoid that, but still iterate over the characters with a bash loop, use `printf` to avoid the newline.

```
printf StackOver | while read -rn1; do echo "$REPLY" ; done
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use word boundaries also..

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=.)(\B|\b)(?=.)/\n/g' <<< "StackOver"
S
t
a
c
k
O
v
e
r
```

Answer (score 3):

In bash:

This works with any text and with only bash internals (no external utility called), so, should be fast on short strings.

```
str="StackOvér áàéèëêếe"

[[ $str =~ ${str//?/(.)} ]]           # Use a regex to split.
printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"  # Print all characters.
```

Output:

```
S
t
a
c
k
O
v
é
r
 
á
à
é
è
ë
ê
ế
e
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s=stackoverflow;

$ time echo $s | fold -w1                                                                                                                                          
s                                                                                                                                                                          
t                                                                                                                                                                          
a                                                                                                                                                                          
c                                                                                                                                                                          
k                                                                                                                                                                          
o                                                                                                                                                                          
v
e
r

real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```

**updates**
here is the hacky|fastest|pureBashBased way !

```
$ time eval eval printf \'%s\\\\n\' \\\${s:\{0..$((${#s}-1))}:1}
s
t
a
c
k
o
v
e
r

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

*for more awesomeness*

```
function foldh () 
{ 
    if (($#)); then
        local s="$@";
        eval eval printf \'%s\\\\n\' \\\"\\\${s:\{0..$((${#s}-1))}:1}\\\";
    else
        while read s; do
            eval eval printf \'%s\\\\n\' \\\"\\\${s:\{0..$((${#s}-1))}:1}\\\";
        done;
    fi
}
function foldv () 
{ 
    if (($#)); then
        local s="$@";
        eval eval echo \\\"\\\${s:\{0..$((${#s}-1))}:1}\\\";
    else
        while read s; do
            eval eval echo \\\"\\\${s:\{0..$((${#s}-1))}:1}\\\";
        done;
    fi
}
```

Comment: Will this ever give different results to [`fold -b1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253562/90751) ?

Comment: since each byte have a width=1 the result will be the same !

Comment: So how is this not a duplicate of [the earlier answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253562/90751)?

Comment: because it shows tha same cmd with different argyment , and that is nice to know .

Comment: This removes white space from the original string.

Comment: An eval could be a big risk, a double `eval` is even more risky. Specially with arbitrary input from `$s`. Just saying !!

Answer (score 1):

```
read -a var <<< $(echo "$yourWordhere" | grep -o "." | tr '\n' ' ')
```

this will split your word and store it in array `var`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in $(echo "$yourWordhere" | grep -o '.')
do
    code to perform operation on individual character $x of your word
done
```

Answer (score 1):

On bash 4.2 and up (I tested 4.2.46 and 5.1), with extglobs you can use and empty "zero or one" match:

```
# shopt -s extglob
# V="StackOverflow"
# echo -e ${V//?()/\\n}
S
t
a
c
k
O
v
e
r
f
l
o
w
```

It also works to split your string into an array:

```
# A=( ${V//?()/ } )
# declare -p A

declare -a A='([0]="S" [1]="t" [2]="a" [3]="c" [4]="k" [5]="O" [6]="v" [7]="e" [8]="r" [9]="f" [10]="l" [11]="o" [12]="w")'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
~$ echo "StackOvér áàéèëêếe" | raku -ne '.chars.put;'
18
~$ echo "StackOvér áàéèëêếe" | raku -ne '.put for .comb;'
S
t
a
c
k
O
v
é
r

á
à
é
è
ë
ê
ế
e
```

https://raku.org/