# How can place a newline before EVERY individual character in a file?

Tags: sed, string, output, input

Ok, I may just be having a dumbass moment. If so, I apologize.
It sounds like a fairly simple task, but I can't get this working:

I'd just like to be able to input a string, and place each individual letter of that string on a new line in the output file.

I've been messing around with `sed` for this, and despite having used it on multiple occasions for other bits and pieces, I can't get it co-operating in this instance.

Can anyone suggest a command that would achieve this?

Ideally, I'd prefer for it to be `sed`-based, but I'm open to alternative solutions.

Many Thanks :)

Comment: This should get you close: [Bash script: split word on each letter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253279/bash-script-split-word-on-each-letter)

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you so much. That's perfect :)